# Determining whether a map on polynomials is properly defined.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

A problem I've been working on (PRIMES 2020 Problem set M3) goes as following:

> Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer and consider the vector space $V$ of real polynomials of degree at most $n$. We define the map $T:V\to V$ by $$f(x)\mapsto \frac{d}{dx}\left[(x+1)^{n+1}\cdot f\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\right].$$ Is $T$ a linear map? If so, compute its determinant.

I was just wondering if $T$ is properly defined here. I was able to prove it is linear and find the determinant, but I'm not sure $T$ is valid in the first place.

The problem states that for every value $k$, $f(k)$ maps to $\frac{d}{dx}\left[(x+1)^{n+1}\cdot f\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\right]$ evaluated at $x=k$. Note that the function that $f(x)$ maps to under $T$ is defined using the function $f\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$, which is not defined when $x=-1$, because that would involve a division by 0. Then, $(x+1)^{n+1}\cdot f\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$ can't be defined at $x=-1$ either, because the multiplication by a function still keeps the discontinuity. The derivative of this function can't be defined at $x=-1$ either, because in order for the derivative of a function $g$ at $x=-1$ to exist, $g(-1)$ needs to exist. It's well known that differentiability implies continuity, so since $(x+1)^{n+1}\cdot f\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$ is not continuous at $x=-1$, it is also not differentiable at $x=-1$.

In short, $T$ maps a $f$ to a function with a discontinuity at $x=-1$. Since it has a discontinuity, $T(f)$ cannot be a polynomial, because it is well known that all polynomials are continuous everywhere.

However, $T$ is supposed to be defined from $V$ to $V$, which means it must map to polynomials.

I was wondering if my logic was correct in saying that $T$ is not well defined because it isn't actually a map from polynomials to polynomials.

Or is it that the values of the function at specific points are for some reason disregarded in a map from polynomials to polynomials? Could somebody help explain how exactly such a function works?

Comment: There are two interpretations here.  One is that they are ignoring the removable discontinuity in this context.  If they were to be technically accurate in the way that you outline, they should really say that
$$
f(x) \mapsto \begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dx}\left[(x+1)^{n+1}\cdot f\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\right] & x \neq 1\\
\lim_{x \to -1} \frac{d}{dx}\left[(x+1)^{n+1}\cdot f\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\right] & x = -1
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probably correct interpretation (which should have been explicitly stated if this is indeed what they mean) is that they are interpreting the polynomial $f(x)$ "formally''. That is, $x$ and its powers, $x^k$, are treated as formal symbols, not as elements of or functions over a field.

So, if $x$ is interpreted as an element of $\Bbb R$ (or of any field) we would have
$$
\frac{x+1}{x+1} = \begin{cases} 1 & x \neq -1\\ \text{undefined} & x = -1\end{cases}.
$$
Nevertheless, we "formally define" $\frac{x+1}{x+1} = 1$.  So, when $f(x)$ is a (formal) polynomial, the corresponding function
$$
(x+1)^{n+1}\cdot f\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)
$$
is also a (formal) polynomial.

Comment: The notion of formal function of $x$ is discussed more formally on [the definition section of this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#Definition) and on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) from wikipedia.